# angular: updating scope on hover

Tags: css, angularjs

I'd like some child div of a main div be hidden by default an visible when you hover over the main div.

I'm trying to have that native in angular and forget the `.hover()` way in jquery.

I though about using `ng-show` on the child div and then updating the binding when I hover the main div. Is there a directive to listen for hovering?

Comment: There isn't a directive for hovering (eg ng-hover), but you can write one! That's the beauty of AngularJS. =)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You're on the right track. You can actually use the ngMouseenter and ngMouseleave directives to do this.

```html
<span ng-mouseenter="show = true" ng-mouseleave="show = false">
  Mouse over me.
</span>

<div ng-show="show">Hello!</div>
```

Here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ro80nR7HT7OGGPCXjz7E?p=preview

@Swordfish0321 is also right - you can write a very simple directive to listen specifically for the hovering if you'd like, but it may not be necessary. We use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` for tooltips in [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap), for example.

Comment: @Josh David Miller. I want to display "Hello" also if I hover on it. And I can not put it as inner div. Any help on this?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @JoshDavidMiller for a very succinct answer. I had a need to do this in an ng-repeat and couldn't quite figure out an elegant way to do it. Using a boolean on the scope was showing the edit controls for all elements in the list instead of just the one I was hovering over. I almost stooped to whipping out `angular.element` (i.e. JQuery) and attaching hover handlers myself so they could manually show just the controls for the hovered element. I am glad I didn't stoop to such evil ways.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseenter="item.showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="item.showEdit = false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" ng-show="item.showEdit"></span>
    Mouse over me.
</div>
```

Simply attach the property to the `item` rather than `$scope`. In a few situations I couldn't add random keys to the items in my list so I mapped my array to a new one where the `item` is actually a property on a wrapper object, then I could attach any properties I wanted to the wrapper object without polluting the `item` keys.

Comment: I had a similar problem that I resolved by explicitly referring to the $parent scope. Before that, when I tried to update the object directly, it just created a new field with the same name in the lower scope.

Comment: @downhand Right, that's because of scope inheritance. You can read inherited properties, but setting them only hides the underlying prototype property rather than overriding it. More of a JavaScript limitation than an Angular one :)