# Binding expression during hover on element and increase performance

Tags: angularjs

In my Angularjs application I have a requirement to show some content(`data-content`) on hover of a element.

```
<div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="month in datelist" on-finish-render="CalLoaded">
    <table class="calender" >
        <caption><span>{{month.monthname}}</span></caption>
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="x in week" >{{ x.weekname }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="monthDate in month.dates">
                <td ng-repeat="weekDate in monthDate.wout" ng-attr-id="{{weekDate.id}}" b-color="{{weekDate.color}}" ng-click="Open(weekDate.id);" data-hover="cal-tooltip" data-content='<table><tr><td<td>{{exp1}}</td><td ........ /td></tr></table>'>
                {{weekDate.win}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The data-content will contain angular binding and it will contain many expression and will be large. So if i do bind all this then it will cause performance issue as it is inside a ng-repeat(having around 100 loops) so there binding for all data-hover will be slow and have lot of DOM elements.

So is there any method where i can bind the data-hover during the user hovers on that td element so that binding will be done only when required and DOM element will be less. Or is there any techniques to increase the performance in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not it would cause performance issues I could not tell you definitively without seeing the data set/volume of binding per popup. However, a simple way to reduce the load on the DOM using angular is to use [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) instead of show/hide (as most libraries do afaik), ng-if actually adds and removes items from the DOM based on the conditional rather than simply setting the display to hidden etc thus vastly reducing the amount of binding that angular will have to do at any given point.

A simple example of this within an ng-repeat would be as follows (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772510/angular-updating-scope-on-hover)):

http://plnkr.co/edit/S4qijIUlh2nd2Y4vQ547?p=preview

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-mouseenter="item.showEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="item.showEdit = false">
    <span ng-if="item.showEdit">Hovered</span>
    Mouse over me.
  </div>
```

And then simply add a show/hide boolean to each item in your list to isolate the hover instantiations. This could also be achieved with a relatively simple directive.

Comment: Ok.Nice!!.. But in my case i want to set data-content to the element based on whether same element is hovered. But the example you shown is based on other element and it can be done just by using mouseenter and ng-if. But how to attach and remove the  data-content for an element based on same element is hovered or not?

Comment: In your example is exp1 not a property of weekDate? My presumption was that within the repeat you want to show an extended properties list of the item within the current iteration on hover, so hover over item2, show in a popup item2.n .

Comment: Actually I guess the issue is that you want to show the popup using bootstrap right? My suggestion is that you don't use bootstrap and style the span in my example as a popup instead (to gain the performance benefits of ng-if)

Comment: Inside the ng-repeat i will have expression inside data-content which are from another array, but it will based on value of weekDate.win. I want to show popup using bootstrap. Is there any alternative?